# Sharpness of Hardy's inequality in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I want to prove that for any constant $C>\frac{1}{4}$, there exists a function $f\in C_c^1(\mathbb R^3)$ such that
$$\int_{\mathbb R^3} \lvert \nabla f(x) \rvert^2 \, dx < C \int_{\mathbb R^3} \frac{\lvert f(x) \rvert^2}{\lvert x \rvert^2} \, dx.$$
At least locally, the function $\lvert x \rvert^{-1/2}$ is the ground state of this functional, i.e. for $\lvert x \rvert^{-1/2}$ we have equality when $C=1/4$ on each bounded region. So the idea is to cut the function off smoothly by a sequence of $C_c^\infty (\mathbb R^3)$ functions and let the cut-off radius go to $0$. However, I couldn't quiet get that to work, since the gradient blows up too fast. Any ideas for an easier way to approach this?

Attempt: Put $\varphi_n(x) := \lvert x \rvert ^{-1/2} \chi_n(x)$ where $\chi_n$ should cut off the function at some arbitrary value, say $1$. But 
we also have to cut out $0$, else the resulting function is no longer $C_c^1(\mathbb R^3)$. My approach was to take $\chi_n \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^3), 0 \leq \chi_n \leq 1$ with $\chi_n \equiv 1$ on $B_{2,3}(0)$ and $\chi_n \equiv 0$ on $B_{2-1/n}(0)$ as well as on $B_{3+1/n}(0)^c$. Then (after some calculations) it suffices to prove that
$$(C-1/4) \int_{B_{2,3}(0)} \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert^3 } \, dx - \int_{B_{2,3}(0)^c} \lvert \nabla \varphi_n(x) \rvert^2 \, dx > 0$$
for sufficiently large $n$. However, I think the best I can expect is $\lvert \nabla \chi_n(x) \rvert^2 \leq n^2$ which is diverging too fast...

Comment: It seems to me that the suggested approach works with no big problem. Exactly what goes  wrong when you try it?

Comment: Assume the cut-off has length $1/n$, when I tried to estimate the error terms, I get that $\lvert \nabla \chi_n(x) \rvert^2 \leq C n^2$ but the integral has order $1/n$ terms in it which is not enough... I'll try it again and maybe edit my answer

Comment: You have to be much  more explicit.  Exactly what cutoff function are you using? "Cutoff has length $1/n$" is unclear...

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Read it, or the comment at the bottom: The answer is wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see the comment. Apparently this is trickier than I thought...